# Perl script (or anything) to total up CSV column

Tags: perl, csv, awk

I wrote (with lots of help from others) an [`awk` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159224/excel-and-awk-disagree-about-csv-totals/4159404#4159404) to total up a column in a CSV file. Unfortunately, I learned after some Googling that `awk` isn't great at handling CSV files due to the fact that the separator is not always the same (i.e. commas should be ignored when surround by quotes).

It seems that perhaps a Perl script could do better. Would it be possible to have a one-line Perl script (or something nearly as succinct) that achieves the same thing as this `awk` command that totals up the 5th column of a CSV file?

```
cat file.csv | awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{s+=$5} END {printf("%01.2f\n", s)}'
```

I'm not married to Perl in particular but I was hoping to avoid writing a full-blown PHP script. By this time I could have easily written a PHP script, but now that I've come this far, I want to see if I can follow it through.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a decent CSV parser to deal with all the complexities of CSV format. [Text::CSV_XS](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV_XS) (or [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV) if that's not avialable) is one of the preferred ones.

```
perl -e '{use Text::CSV_XS; my $csv=Text::CSV_XS->new(); open my $fh, "<", "file.csv" or die "file.csv: $!"; my $sum = 0; while (my $row = $csv->getline ($fh)) {$sum += $row->[4]}; close $fh; print "$sum\n";}'
```

Here's the actual Perl code, for better readability

```
use Text::CSV_XS; # use the parser library
my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new(); # Create parser object
open my $fh, "<", "file.csv" or die "file.csv: $!"; # Open the file. 
my $sum = 0; 
while (my $row = $csv->getline ($fh)) { # $row is array of field values now
    $sum += $row->[4];
}
close $fh; 
print "$sum\n";
```

---

**The above could be shortened by using slightly lesser quality but denser Perl**:

```
cat file.csv | perl -MText::CSV_XS -nae '$csv=Text::CSV_XS->new(); 
               $csv->parse($_); @f=$csv->fields(); $s+=$f[4]} { print "$s\n"'
```

Comment: I don't know Perl, but that `} {` looks odd in your dense version. Are there implied `{` and `}` in the `-n` loop that you don't have to supply?

Comment: Your version with `cat` would not work well with CSV file containing multi-line string field.

Comment: @Dennis - `} { foo` is an abbreviated version of `END{ foo }`

Answer (score 3):

Are you opposed to using a Perl module?  You can use [Text::CSV](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV) to do this easily without rolling your own parser.

[Tutorial](http://perlmeme.org/tutorials/parsing_csv.html) snippet changed to perform total:

```
# ... some tutorial code ommited
while (<CSV>) {
    if ($csv->parse($_)) {
        my @columns = $csv->fields();
        $total += $columns[4];
    } else {
        my $err = $csv->error_input;
        print "Failed to parse line: $err";
    }
}
print "total: $total\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Python

```
import csv
with open( "some_file.csv", "rb" ) as source:
    rdr= csv.reader( source )
    col_5= 0
    for row in rdr:
        col_5 += row[5]
print col_5
```

Not a one-liner, but pretty terse.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of tools that do this.  A quick search for 'cli csvparser' lead me to several tools (which I apparently can't link to--possibly to prevent spamming).

I installed the first one I found--csvtool--and was able to do a similar command line as yours and get a total.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty short (and fast) solution:

```
perl -MText::CSV_XS -E'$c=new Text::CSV_XS;$s+=$r->[4]while$r=$c->getline(*ARGV);say$s' file.csv
```