# Parse CSV cell by cell

Tags: perl, parsing, csv

I have a CSV file with a lot of columns and rows but I need to sum cells of certain column:

```
Samples | Name | Value1 | Value2 | Value3

A-Sample | A-Name | 1 | 32 | 27 | 21

B-Sample | B-Name | 2 | 23 | 12 | 13

C-Sample | C-Name | 3 | 10 | 98 | 59

D-Sample | D-Name | 4 | 21 | 78 | 72

E-Sample | E-Name | 5 | 32 | 72 | 27
```

I need Sum of cells in column `Value 1`, Sum of cells in column `Value2`. I'm trying to use Text::CSV, but I only get the result as lines.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Can you show a small part of the Perl code that shows what you tried?

Comment: Check module Text::CSV on CPAN.

Comment: if you do it yourself, 
first read in the CSV file.
For every line in the file, split on the delimiter ("|"). This gives you an array for that line of values.
Based on the column indexes you want to sum, keep a running total of those indexes from the array.

But why reinvent the wheel, use Text::CSV, as suggested

Comment: This related topic may assist you: [Perl script (or anything) to total up CSV column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159695/perl-script-or-anything-to-total-up-csv-column)

Answer (score 0):

try Spreadsheet::Read, maybe it fit's your needs. With this module you can use a csv like any other Spreadsheet. See perldoc Spreadsheet::Read or https://metacpan.org/module/Spreadsheet::Read for more informations.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use Modern::Perl '2012';

use Spreadsheet::Read;
use Data::Dumper;

my $spreadsheet = my $ref = ReadData ("test.csv", sep => "|"); 
my @rows = Spreadsheet::Read::rows ($spreadsheet->[1]);
my @values = map {$_->[4] } @rows; # columns starting with 0
say Dumper (\@values);
```

**output**

```
$VAR1 = [
      'Value3',
      '27',
      '12',
      '98',
      '78',
      '72'
    ];
```

Comment: Thank you, I modified the function so that I could go through all columns. But now I'm stuck in the result of the code:  
while (<INPUT>)  
{  
my @Column  = split ("\t", $_);  
if ($Column[2] =~ m/3/)  
{  
print "$Column[3]\n";  
}}  I got 10 as the answer instead all string in $Column[3]. Why?

Comment: Hi, can you please provide more code and edit your Question? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My favourite module for this kind of thing is Tie::Array::CSV

```
use Tie::Array::CSV;
tie my @csv, 'Tie::Array::CSV', 'filename.csv' or die;
my @answer;         # store the results
for (my $row = 1; $row < @csv; $row++) # each row if the csv
{
    next unless $row->[2] =~ /^\s*\d+\s*$/; # Not rows where 3rd field isn't numeric
    for (my $i = 2; $i < @$row; $i++)  # cols 2 onwards
    {
        $answer[$i] += $row->[$i];  # sum the results
    }
 }
 say "@answer[2 .. $#answer]"; # display the sums
```

Answer (score 0):

I work with a lot of CSV files and my favorite modules by far are [Tie::Handle::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~danboo/Tie-Handle-CSV/lib/Tie/Handle/CSV.pm) and [DBD::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~hmbrand/DBD-CSV/lib/DBD/CSV.pm).

perlmeme.org has a fantastic [tutorial](http://perlmeme.org/tutorials/parsing_csv.html) on parsing CSV files.